# Generate string of fixed length in C#

Tags: string, c#-4.0

How can I generate a string of fixed length based on the input given in c#.

```
For example :
string s="1";
string newstring ;
I want the newstring to be "AB_000001";
// Similarly if 
s="xyz";
//I want the newstring as 
newstring = "AB_000xyz";
```

Comment: What approaches have you taken to solve this? What code have you written and why is it not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String s = "AB_000000";
String newString="xyz";
s = s.Remove(s.Length - newString.Length, newString.Length);
s = s + newString;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string basestr = "AB_000000";
string inp = "xyz";
string res = basestr.Substring(0, basestr.Length - inp.Length) + inp;
```